# Reconnct to database isn't happening after Mule starts

Tags: database, mule, reconnect

I am trying the Reconnection configuration in Mule for database connection. My goal is to make Mule retry the connection if the database is down, or at least keep the message somewhere so that I can post the message again later. 
So I configure the Reconnection in the jdbc connector as followed:

```
<jdbc-ee:connector name="MyDatabase" dataSource-ref="DB2_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
    <reconnect frequency="6000" count="8"/>
</jdbc-ee:connector>
```

It works if I start Mule when database is down. I can see in the log that Mule is retrying the reconnect.

The problem comes when the database is down after Mule has already started. I tried by shutting down my database after I ran the flow. I don't see Mule trying to reconnect to the database. When I post a message that hits the database endpoint, it just throws a SQLException and doesn't try to reconnect. Thus my message is lost.

Is there a way to make Mule retry the connection if database is down after Mule starts and log the error somewhere if the retry fails?

Comment: Did you able to resolve this case?. I have a similar kind of problem.

Comment: Hi @star, no, I haven't received answer for this question. What I can do is to have a catch exception strategy that push my message to a MQ when encountering such an exception. I wish I could make the reconnect works. Let me know if you find anything. Thanks.